I get an error when using libtorch in Rust on windows 11
I wanted to create a program in Rust that uses libtorch to read yolo models and identify what is on the screen, but I am stuck at the beginning of the process.
I am using windows 11.
Below is the error at build time and some information that may be relevant.
Can someone please help me?
I am Japanese. Forgive me if my English is strange.
ERROR
PS C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\yolo_screen_capture_rs> cargo build
   Compiling torch-sys v0.5.0
   Compiling opencv v0.92.0
The following warnings were emitted during compilation:

warning: torch-sys@0.5.0: ToolExecError: Command "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.40.33807\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\cl.exe" "-nologo" "-MD" "-Z7" "-Brepro" "-I" "\"C:\\libtorch-win-shared-with-deps-2.3.1+cu121\\libtorch\"\\include" "-I" "\"C:\\libtorch-win-shared-with-deps-2.3.1+cu121\\libtorch\"\\include/torch/csrc/api/include" "-FoC:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\yolo_screen_capture_rs\\target\\debug\\build\\torch-sys-d2321bf5133b1225\\out\\19072f24a82f85ae-torch_api.o" "-c" "libtch/torch_api.cpp" with args cl.exe did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 2).

error: failed to run custom build command for `torch-sys v0.5.0`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\yolo_screen_capture_rs\target\debug\build\torch-sys-874e9c7041f962a4\build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
  --- stderr


  error occurred: Command "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.40.33807\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\cl.exe" "-nologo" "-MD" "-Z7" "-Brepro" "-I" "\"C:\\libtorch-win-shared-with-deps-2.3.1+cu121\\libtorch\"\\include" "-I" "\"C:\\libtorch-win-shared-with-deps-2.3.1+cu121\\libtorch\"\\include/torch/csrc/api/include" "-FoC:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\yolo_screen_capture_rs\\target\\debug\\build\\torch-sys-d2321bf5133b1225\\out\\19072f24a82f85ae-torch_api.o" "-c" "libtch/torch_api.cpp" with args cl.exe did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 2).

List of Environment Variables
PS C:\Users\xxx> Get-ChildItem Env:
Name                           Value
----                           -----

CUDA_PATH                      C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.1
CUDA_PATH_V12_1                C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.1
DevEnvDir                      C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\
EXTERNAL_INCLUDE               C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include
INCLUDE                        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include
LIB                            C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\ATLM
LIBPATH                        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\ATLM
LIBTORCH                       "C:\libtorch-win-shared-with-deps-2.3.0+cu121\libtorch"
LIBTORCH_INCLUDE               "C:\libtorch-win-shared-with-deps-2.3.0+cu121\libtorch\include"
LIBTORCH_LIB                   "C:\libtorch-win-shared-with-deps-2.3.0+cu121\libtorch\lib"
OPENCV_INCLUDE_PATHS           C:\opencv\build\include
OPENCV_LINK_LIBS               opencv_world4100.lib
OPENCV_LINK_PATHS              C:\opencv\build\x64\vc16\lib
Path                           C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\bin\...
VCPKG_ROOT                     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\vcpkg
VCToolsInstallDir              C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\

Visual Studio 2022 Developer PowerShell v17.10.4
PS C:\Users\xxx\source\repos> cl
Microsoft(R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.40.33812 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "yolo_screen_capture_rs"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
tch = "0.5.0"
opencv = "0.92.0"

build.rs
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=build.rs");
    println!("cargo:include=C:\\libtorch-win-shared-with-deps-2.3.0+cu121\\libtorch\\include");
    println!("cargo:lib=C:\\libtorch-win-shared-with-deps-2.3.0+cu121\\libtorch\\lib");
}

libtorch installs the following
Addendum: The torch version specified in tch-rs was 2.3.0.
I have lowered libtorch ver from 2.3.1 to 2.3.0 just in case the torch version specified by tch-rs was 2.3.0.

Download here (Release version):
https://download.pytorch.org/libtorch/cu121/libtorch-win-shared-with-deps-2.3.0%2Bcu121.zip

The following is the result of a test with an appropriate cpp file to confirm that cl works and that libtorch can be included.
PS C:\Users\xxx\Desktop> cl -I"C:\libtorch-win-shared-with-deps-2.3.0+cu121\libtorch\include" -I"C:\libtorch-win-shared-with-deps-2.3.0+cu121\libtorch\include\torch\csrc\api\include" -c test.cpp
>> 
>>
Microsoft(R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.40.33812 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

We have re-installed the environment for c++ desktop using the visualStudio installer.
I checked the libtorch path and if the executable is actually there.
